# Cannot install WWW::Mechanize Under proxy

Tags: perl, proxy, www-mechanize

OS: Linux.
Perl Version: 5.16.0 (using Perlbrew).

I was trying to install Catalyst, and I got failed tests exactly as described in:

http://stevemoss.posterous.com/installing-wwwmechanize-and-testwwwmechanize

I am running under proxy in my workplace, I have set the http_proxy in ~/.cpan/CPAN/Config.pm and also set the no_proxy to each of the following with no success:
1. local host.
2. 127.0.0.1 (local host ip).
3. A known http server I have tested working without proxy.
4. Blank.

Here are the failed tests log, the last one doesn't even end, and it is stuck at 44/47:

```
rlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl
# Test::Memory::Cycle 1.04 is installed.
t/00-load.t .............. ok   
t/add_header.t ........... ok   
t/aliases.t .............. ok   
t/area_link.t ............ ok   
t/autocheck.t ............ ok   
t/clone.t ................ ok   
t/content.t .............. ok   
t/cookies.t .............. # Test server http://127.0.0.1:22443 as PID 4655
t/cookies.t .............. ok     
t/credentials-api.t ...... Use of uninitialized value in lc at /perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/site_perl/5.16.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 605.
t/credentials-api.t ...... ok   
t/credentials.t .......... ok     
t/die.t .................. ok   
t/field.t ................ ok   
t/find_frame.t ........... ok   
t/find_image.t ........... ok     
t/find_inputs.t .......... ok     
t/find_link-warnings.t ... ok     
t/find_link.t ............ ok     
t/find_link_id.t ......... ok    
t/form-parsing.t ......... ok   
t/form_with_fields.t ..... 1/? There are 2 forms with the named fields.  The first one was used. at t/form_with_fields.t line 27.
t/form_with_fields.t ..... ok   
t/frames.t ............... ok   
t/image-new.t ............ ok     
t/image-parse.t .......... ok     
t/link-base.t ............ ok   
t/link-relative.t ........ ok   
t/link.t ................. ok     
t/local/back.t ........... 44/47
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that are not important problems. You can force module install:

```
cpan -f -i WWW::Mechanize
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is obviously not that your CPAN clients fails to use the proxy correctly (it managed to download the package after all), but that the module you are installing either doesn't know about the proxy or isn't ready to handle a proxy.

If the module you are trying to install cannot handle, proxies, you're out of luck.

If it can, tell it to use your proxy by setting the relevant environment variable:

```
export http_proxy="http://your.proxy.goes.here"
```

Answer (score 1):

For local/back.t (and several others tests), `http_proxy` is temporarily disabled. It's possible that you are suffering from a race condition where the temporary server (created in the test) isn't destroyed before http_proxy is reactivated.

Fortunately, `no_proxy` is not disabled during the tests and it should be able to fix the problem. Just make certain to set it to "localhost" rather than "local host", as you had written for option #1.

If that doesn't work, check that NO_PROXY is being configured correctly by temporarily setting it to an external site (and fail to reach it). Of course, taking away all mention of http_proxy is another option but that's sometimes awkward and should lead to other tests failing.

Comment: I guess there is no really satisfying solution to this problem, but I don't want the bounty to go to waste, and your answer was the most informative to me.